# Uable to build release apk

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem signing an APK.

Error:

> Error: xpp3 defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

Below is my Build.gradle content..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'converter-gson', version: '2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.kevinsawicki:http-request:6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.7.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.5'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile ('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You need to exclude `xpp3` on the dependency that is using this. Something like - `exclude group: ‘xpp3’, module: ‘xpp3’`.  Also this will be rejected by playstore using `com.example` as your namespace

Comment: Thanks  alot... slove the issue by adding compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0'){
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    }